# Can async functions be called in onClick in button react

Tags: reactjs

I am going to call async function in `onclick` event in button. But it is not working. Is it possible to call the async function inside button onlick ?

Here is the code.

**Filter button**

```
const FilterButton = (props) => {

return (
    <div className="p-2 ">
        <button className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={props.fetchInvoices}>Filter</button>
    </div>
 );
};
```

fetchInvoices async function

```
fetchInvoices = async () => {
    const invoices = await getInvoices(this.currentState.params);
    this.props.store.dispatch(UpdateInvoices(invoices));
};
```

code to pass function to component

```
 <SearchField store = {this.props.store} fetchInvoices={this.fetchInvoices}/>
```

Comment: It will work. What's the error?

Comment: Now it is working.  This fetchInvoice in SeachField is passed as a parameter. I added fetchInvoices={this.fetchInvoices} instead fetchInvoices={this.props.fetchInvoices}

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This is how I call my asyncs inside an `onClick`:

```
<Button onClick={async () => {await this.asyncFunc("Example");} }/>

async asyncFunc(text) {
    console.log(text);
}
```

Comment: I think this is just the same as:

<Button onClick={() => {this.asyncFunc("Example");} }/>

Comment: This does nothing helpful. Async delegate is executed without waiting for its result.

Comment: It helps not to trigger on click function on document load, only on click

Comment: @IgorAtsberger Yes if you pass some parameters to async/normal function you need to create empty lambda function which will pass those parameters.
```
<Button onClick={async () => await asyncFunc(param1, param2)}/>

// even this is ok
```
<Button onClick={() => asyncFunc(param1, param2)}/>
```
```

But if you do not pass any parameters, passing just function reference is sufficient.
```
<Button onClick={asyncFunc}/>
<Button onClick={normalFunc}/>
```

Answer (score 11):

Your [async function](https://javascript.info/async-await):

```
const asyncFunc = async () => {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve("I am a done promise!"), 3000)
    });

    let result = await promise

    alert(result);
}
```

Your [button component](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) call:

```
<button onClick={asyncFunc} >I am a button!</button>
```

Answer (score -4):

Instead, try doing

```
<button className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={this.handleFetchInvoices}>Filter</button>
handleFetchInvoices(){
this.props.fetchInvoices
}
```

Comment: This does nothing. It should be:

handleFetchInvoices() {
  this.props.fetchInvoices();
}

Answer (score -4):

```
<button 
  onClick={(e) => (async () => {
    try {
      const invoices = await getInvoices(this.currentState.params);
    } catch () {

    }
  })()} 
>I am a button!</button>
```

In general, it is a bad practice to create an **2x** functions inside the button with each click. But it works.