# Add back button when loading url in Electron

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

I currently have elements in an Electron app of mine, that when clicking on them loads a url. However it is not possible to go to the previous (local) page.

Is there any way to add a layered back button on top of the external url which will load the previous page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't had a need to use it but there are navigation functions in the [webContent](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsgoback) instances:

> **contents.clearHistory()**
>
> Clears the navigation history.
>
> **contents.goBack()**
>
> Makes the browser go back a web page.
>
> **contents.goForward()**
>
> Makes the browser go forward a web page.

And so forth. So it looks like you can do what you want.

Comment: How can i call them after loading the url? Is there anyway to run a javascript file from an external url?

Comment: @ThanosTapras - it really depends on how your app is structured, If you are not familiar with IPC communication, you should spend a couple of hours reading tutorials and writing some test code.

Answer (score 5):

Here In your Page wherever
Don't forget to

```
const electron = window.require('electron');
const { ipcRenderer } = electron;
```

#### App.js (or any page)

```
const goBack = async () => {
  // Async message sender
  ipcRenderer.send('goBackHomeBoi', 'Send Me Data Please')
  // Async message handler
  ipcRenderer.on('WentBack', (event, data) => {
    console.log(data)
  })
}
```

then you can have button on the page whose `onClick` binds to this funtion.

#### main.js (electron main)

```
 // Event handler for asynchronous incoming messages
ipcMain.on('goBackHomeBoi', async (event, arg) => {
    win.webContents.goBack()
    event.sender.send('WentBack', 'Done')
 })
```

Comment: dumb question...can you show me how the onClick works for this?

Comment: nvm found it https://stackoverflow.com/a/66986263/5954452